# javascript arrays: adding entries

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I'm not sure how I would do this in Javascript.
I want to create an array that would contain any number of error messages from my form.

I read on websites that you define the key for that array when adding new entries.

```
// Javascript
var messages = new Array();
messages[0] = 'Message 1';
```

How can I add entries into my array using a similar method I normally do in PHP

```
// PHP    
$messages = array();
$messages[] = 'Message 1'; // automatically assigned key 0
$messages[] = 'Message 2'; // automatically assigned key 1
```

Is it possible to emulate that in Javascript? I don't want to have to define the number of entries in my array as it can vary.

Thanks for helping me out on this very basic js question.
-Lyon

Comment: @Lyon: This is one of those questions that can be answered by googling their title and reading the first result.

Comment: @Tomalak: And the goal according to Joel is that the question on stackoverflow is that first result google returns and _the_ best answer you can find on the web.

Comment: @Volker: Ahhhh, that's a lame excuse and you know it. Even *if* the first result and best possible answer would be a Stack Overflow page... when people are not googling for an answer before asking away happily that wouldn't make much of a difference, would it. Apart from that I don't think it's SO's misssion to re-create all the programming knowledge in the world (because it's not "real" when it is not on SO and reading the spec is lame, or what?).

Comment: @Tomalak: There certainly discussion about that on http://meta.stackoverflow.com e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4448/does-so-encourage-developer-laziness

Comment: @Tomalak with all due respect, i did my fair share of googling and checking out javascript array resources. The fact that I was searching for an answer similar to php's solution probably led to me never encountering the .push() method. With SO, I am able to present what I know in PHP, and ask the SO community on how best to do the same in Javascript. Google won't tell me that.

Comment: @Lyon: http://www.google.com/search?&q=javascript+array+append+item - it even turns up a result from Stack Overflow among the first five. I appreciate that your focus on PHP in this matter maybe stood in your way when searching. But it's not exactly secret knowledge, and there are enough pages that explain JS array objects as a whole and would have been worth a read alternatively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var messages = new Array();
messages.push('Message 1');
messages.push('Message 2');
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 7 seconds. ;) +1

Comment: For the definition in ecmascript 3rd edition see http://www.mozilla.org/js/language/E262-3.pdf @ "15.4.4.7 Array.prototype.push"

Answer (score 2):

```
messages.push('Message n');
```

that should do the trick :)

reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/Push)